# Populate listbox with headers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate a listbox from a list of items, I can get it to populate but it is taking in my header row as a row in the list and the headers are blank. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be great.

```
Sub populateList()
  Dim rngName As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  Set ws = Worksheets("ProjectData")
  lbTasks.Clear
  lbTasks.ColumnHeads = True
  lbTasks.ColumnCount = 10
  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 1 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 5).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 7).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 8).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 7) = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 9).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 8) = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 10).Value <> vbNullString Then lbTasks.List(i - 1, 9) = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only use `ColumnHeads` if the listbox is populated using a range address in the `Rowsource`/`ListFillRange` (depending on where the listbox is).

Comment: I have created a user form that holds the Listbox. So how else can  I populate the headers, the header row is visible in the listbox but has no text

Comment: As I said, you have to put the data into a range on a sheet, then specify the RowSource as that range's address, excluding the header row.

Comment: Is there anyway I can ignore the header from being added to the list?

Comment: You could capture the range that has the values and then delete empty rows from the range ([see this on how to delete empty rows from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045885/delete-blank-cells-in-range)) before using the range to populate the listbox

Comment: Change the loop to start at 2 not 1.

Comment: Have you considered using a ListView control?